# regex pattern concatenation in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following pattern to match percentage from the below cases

```
76.39% (based on 206 issue)
1.23% (based on 197)
81.06% based on 206,390,020 fully  issue
12.02
16.59
81.61%
45
24.812
51.35
19348952
88.22
0
000
021
.85%
100
1 67.08% 
2 70.98%
```

Expected:

```
76.39
1.23
81.06
12.02
16.59
81.61
45
24.812
51.35

88.22
0
000
21
.85
100
67.08
70.98
pattern1= r'(\d+\.\d+%)'
df['var']=df['var'].astype(str).str.extract(pattern1)[0]


pattern2 = r'^(?:0{0,})((?:[1-9]{1,2}|100)?(?:\.\d+)?)%?$'
df['var']=df['var'].astype(str).str.extract(pattern2)[0]
```

Is there any way they can be combined  into single regex pattern to match all the cases?

Note: The example cases that I used are only a fraction of many unique percentage types. So I need a solution that extracts the percentage only (up to 2 decimal points). Some characteristics of those include - * after % ;% followed by another % in percentage; sometimes special characters such as * @ # are before and after the percentage

Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex only to split on `%` or a whitespace, then apply `float` to the first item:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

data ='''76.39% (based on 206 issue)
1.23% (based on 197)
81.06% based on 206,390,020 fully  issue
12.02
16.59
81.61%
45
24.812
51.35
19348952
88.22
0
000
021
.85%
100'''

df = pd.DataFrame(data.splitlines(), columns=['text'])
df['var'] = df['text'].str.strip(string.punctuation + string.ascii_letters).str.split(r'%|\s').str[0].astype(float).apply(lambda x: x if x <= 100.0 else np.nan)
```

Output:

|  | text | var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 76.39% (based on 206 issue) | 76.39 |
| 1 | 1.23% (based on 197) | 1.23 |
| 2 | 81.06% based on 206,390,020 fully issue | 81.06 |
| 3 | 12.02 | 12.02 |
| 4 | 16.59 | 16.59 |
| 5 | 81.61% | 81.61 |
| 6 | 45 | 45 |
| 7 | 24.812 | 24.812 |
| 8 | 51.35 | 51.35 |
| 9 | 19348952 | nan |
| 10 | 88.22 | 88.22 |
| 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 000 | 0 |
| 13 | 021 | 21 |
| 14 | .85% | 0.85 |
| 15 | 100 | 100 |

Comment: so it is reading the examples as string. I am reading it from a csv file and getting a AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'splitlines'. And I am using it - df['text']=df['text'].astype(str).splitlines()

Comment: Forget the splitlines, that's just for making a reproducible answer. In your case you only have to run: `df['var'] = df['var'].astype(str).str.split(r'%|\s').str[0].astype(float).apply(lambda x: x if x <= 100.0 else np.nan)`

Comment: I tried that as well. Got "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[000]'".  Anyway, I could avoid this error?

Comment: This string starts with a punctuation mark, which was not foreseen in your sample data. This makes my entire answer meaningless. A quick hack would be to add `[` to the separators, to the disadvantage that that value will render `nan` rather than `0`: `df['var'] = df['var'].astype(str).str.split(r'[|%|\s').str[0].astype(float).apply(lambda x: x if x <= 100.0 else np.nan)`

Comment: I understand that. It is not always possible to add in all edge cases, especially for large and messy dataset.  Anyway, should it not have a " ] " after the r'[ |%| ] \s' ?  If I use the code as it is I get an "error: unterminated character set" and if I use " ] "  for the character set,  I get other "ValueError : could not convert string to float: [ #### ] ".  I understand that there are other strings in the dataset that is not in the cases (that I put) and could give me a "ValueError".  Is there any way this can be avoided? Appreciate the prolonged help.

Comment: @non_linear I have updated the answer with a solution that should be able to solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for that. I am still getting the following error  (ValueError: could not convert string to float:  ''). To avoid this, I tried  df['var'].str.replace(' ', '').astype(float) before applying your solution  but still get the previous "ValueError with a different string.. I also tried to replace  (  '' ) with a str.replace method , did not work either..Not sure what else should I try? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `)` to `str.split`: `.str.split(r')|%|\s')`

Comment: Did that. got an error :unbalanced parenthesis . I escaped that with a backslash (\) .str.split(r'\)|%|\s' and then I got those ValueError . Also the escaped ( \) backslash is not showing in the commented code line.

Comment: Could you share your full dataset, that would make debugging much easier for me!

Comment: Is it possible to share large file ? Or could we do it here via private chat option? Please let me know.

Comment: @non_linear You need a precise definition of all the input formats you need to process. It sounds like this is not very well defined, which will make writing a function to parse it reliably very difficult.

Comment: @Barmar I understand your point and I edited the question multiple times to clarify it. The data is quite messy (and large) so my inputs somewhat represents roughly 90-95% of the different percentage types in my data. So if I can extract those 90-95% then, I can somewhat discard or manually clean the rest.  I hope this clarifies the situation a bit. Thank you.